# Word 2010 - Adding form field to table

Tags: ms-word

I have a table within word which is protected, but I want to add a user text form field into the table:

For some reason when trying to do it I get: 'You cannot paste form fields into, comments, headers, footer, footnotes, endnotes, or text boxes'

Comment: This is not about programming. Voting to move to superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok sussed it out, the table was actually embedded within a text box and wasn't allowing the control to be added.